# Setting timezone for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

Im using php to set the current timezone for a site:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

How could I, at the same time, set the same time zone for mysql so that when I use NOW() it uses the timezone set in php?

Comment: You could do so in `php.ini` directly instead, if you need so.

Comment: @Lion This is for multiple sites, so I need to load it on a per site basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't.

The best practice is to store `UTC` in the database.

Comment: The sites are geo based, so I need to be accurate with time for rows in the database.

Comment: @John that doesn't change the fact that you should store the datetimes as UTC in the database. Always. You convert them to the relevant locale when they're retrieved. Any other method is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @rdlowrey So set the timezone for mysql to UTC and use NOW() and then convert to the proper timezone for whatever timezone the site is currently in?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your Mysql timezone using `SET time_zone = timezone;`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html